# Sheaf classifier for topoi

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

Categories of sheaves in $[C, \text{Set}]_{\text{Cat}}$ (functor category) are equivalently left exact reflective subcategories of presheaf toposes. Categories of sheaves on a topos $[C, \text{Set}]_{\text{Cat}}$ are also in correspondence with Lawvere Tierney topologies on $[C, \text{Set}]_{\text{Cat}}$.

Is there a topos $\underline{\Omega}$ such that geometric morphisms from $T$ to $\underline{\Omega}$ are in correspondence with Lawvere-Tierney topologies on $T$?

This is like asking for a classifier of categories of sheaves on a topos.

Comment: I am not sure that this is possible, $\text{Topoi}(\text{Set}^C, \Omega) \cong \text{pt}(\Omega^{C^{\circ}})$ is an accessible category with directed colimits, while $\text{LT}(\text{Set}^C)$ is a Heyting algebra which is in general lacking of directed colimits.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti I also don't think that it is possible, but I don't think I'm convinced by that argument: since $Set^C$ is a _Grothendieck_ topos, isn't $LT(Set^C)$ actually a _complete_ Heyting algebra?

Comment: @MikeShulman, you might be right, but in every reference that I find and I've ever read on the topic only finite limits and finite colimits are mentioned [Johnstone A.4.5.10].

Comment: @MikeShulman Borceux and Kelly prove me wrong in "On locales of localizations", Prop. 6.5. Thanks for your remark.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti Also, the construction of binary joins in A4.5.14(a) of the Elephant works for arbitrary joins as soon as the topos is cocomplete.